# Broken zen-grids with external compass and codekit

Tags: drupal, sass, codekit, zen, compass

I'm using drupal and Zen grids with compass. Till the last week all works fantastic. I'm using Codekit with an external gem compass in my native OS ruby install since my rvm doesn't work. 
So I upgrade my Codekitt app to the version 2.1.5 and now I'm in hell. I don't know why I just not able to get my grid to works, here's an example of what I have done :

```
#page {
$zen-column-count:6;
$zen-gutter-width: 20px;
$zen-auto-include-item-base: true;
@include zen-grid-container;
}

#block-block-3 {
   @include zen-clear();
   @include zen-grid-item(6, 1);

   .echange{
       @include zen-grid-item(1, 2);
    }
   .efficacite{
       @include zen-grid-item(1, 3);
    }
    .charge{
        @include zen-grid-item(1, 4);
     }
    .soin{
        @include zen-grid-item(1, 5);
     }
}
```

I'm having problems with this section in particular, It seems like the grid is broken, I tested a lot of ways to fix this but nothing works, do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The problem is what, exactly?  Have you tried searching the zen grid repo?  https://github.com/JohnAlbin/zen-grids/issues/68

Comment: Even when I use an older version of compass I have the same problem (zen adds margin-left:400%) I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this : https://www.drupal.org/node/2188263
It seems for the moment you must use this config in order to run correctly zen grids :

```
gem "sass", "3.2.14"
gem "compass", "0.12.3"
gem "zen-grids", "1.4"
```

More details in the link response number : 18#